# I want to bind the localstorage-retrieved objects contents back to the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage

I want to bind the local storage objects content to the form fields ?

```
 function saveToLocalStorage () {

    var formData= JSON.stringify($('form').serialize());
    var purchaseInoice = localStorage.setItem('PI',formData);
    var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('PI');
    console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
    // alert("Saved as a Draft..!");
     }
```

Comment: What have you tried? What were your results? How can we help?

Comment: I want to autosave data (object)as draft using local storage.And after some interval when I get back to form I want to show autosaved data...i.e to retrieve object from local storage and bind back to form fields ?

Comment: Yes, you've explained what you want. But, how about the answers to the questions I've asked. We're not a code writing service. What have you attempted? What results did you get? What is the specific problem that you are having?

Comment: I want to know how to bind the objects content back to the form fields ?